# Identify missing rows between two tables

Tags: mysql

After many attempts, I give up. I hope for some help me with the following problem:

The Table1.Field should be compared to Table2.Field.

As a resuot, I expect a list as follows:

```
| IssueKey   | Field           | ChangeDate |  
|------------|-----------------|------------|
| HAPP-1000  | Severity        | (null)     |
| HAPP-1000  | Risk Severity   | (null)     |
| HAPP-1000  | Risk Occurance  | (null)     |
| HAPP-1000  | Risk Detection  | (null)     |
```

These are the Table2.Field values that are NOT matched:
This is to detect what Table1.Field values are missing, based on all the possible Table2.Field.

Table1:

```
| IssueKey  | Field       | ChangeDate          |  
|-----------|-------------|---------------------|  
| HAPP-1000 | assignee    | 21/05/2019 11:13:54 |  
| HAPP-1000 | status      | 21/05/2019 11:14:48 |  
| HAPP-1000 | assignee    | 22/05/2019 09:43:01 |  
| HAPP-1000 | Fix Version | 22/05/2019 11:42:15 |  
| HAPP-1000 | assignee    | 22/05/2019 11:42:15 |  
| HAPP-1000 | resolution  | 22/05/2019 11:42:15 |  
| HAPP-1000 | status      | 22/05/2019 11:42:15 |
```

Table2:

```
| Field         |  
|---------------|  
|resolution     |  
|status         |
|Fix Version    |
|Severity       |
|Version        |
|assignee       |  
|Risk Severity  |
|Risk Occurance |  
|Risk Detection | 
|Risk Group Type|
```

I did several variations on:

```
SELECT h.IssueKey, h.Field, j.HistoryField 
FROM History h 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN JIRA_values j ON j.HistoryField = h.Field 
            and IssueKey = 'HAPP-1000'
```

Comment: Show us at least one of your attempts

Comment: I did several variations on:
SELECT h.IssueKey, h.Field, j.HistoryField
FROM History h
LEFT OUTER JOIN JIRA_values j
ON j.HistoryField = h.Field
  and IssueKey = 'HAPP-1000'

Which led to results like:
IssueKey Field HistoryField
HBPL-3410 Fix Version (null)
HBPL-3410 Fix Version (null)
HBPL-3396 Fix Version (null)
HBPL-3396 assignee (null)
HBPL-3396 status (null)
HBPL-3396 assignee (null)
HBPL-3396 Version (null)

In short: a mess. Sorry. It made my weekend hell.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can't have this exact output. You ask for the entries of Table2 that don't have a match in Table1 but  `IssueKey` and `ChangeDate` are columns from Table2. As there is no match there are no values for the two...

Based on your condition `Field` is all you can show:

```
SELECT NULL AS IssueKey, t2.Field, NULL AS ChangeDate          
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.Field = t2.Field 
WHERE t1.Field IS NULL;
```

Answer to your comment:

Based on your comment I assume that Table1 is actually longer and there are multiple `IssueKey`. In that case you want to

1. cross join a list of all possible `IssueKey` and all possible `Field` which will give you a list of all possible combinations between the two
2. this can then be joined on Table1 to identify the combinations that you actually have in Table1
3. finally be filtered for only the ones where there is no match between the output oft he cross join and table1

Should look something like this:

```
SELECT x.IssueKey, y.Field 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IssueKey FROM Table1) x 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Field FROM Table2) y
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON (x.IssueKey = t1.IssueKey AND y. Field = t1. Field)
WHERE t1.IssueKey IS NULL;
```

The result will be a list of combinations between `IssueKey` and `ChangeDate` - but only the ones that are not in Table1

Comment: Indeed the results I got by fiddling with LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN (which seem a logical solution as I saw the VENN-diagrams) either gave me (null) on the Table1 results OR (null) on the Table 2 results. So you are completely right.

However, if I know what values are possible (Table2.Field), and I know the values I actually have (Table1.Field), then how to get a list of (IssueKey, Field) combinations with Field values of the respective IssueKey that are missing?

Comment: added a possible way to my answer - note that you still wont be able to populate `ChangeDate` because it does not exist..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT          table1.ID
```

FROM            table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
WHERE           table2.ID IS NULL